# почему экранируется вывод Html::a(

Tags: yii2

У меня есть простейший код

```
'value' => function ($model) {
return Html::a(текст, $model->getUrl(), ['style' => ['font-size' => '10px']]);                                                }
```

но вместо обычной ссылки yii2 мне генерирует заэкранированный текст

> <a href="/provider/order?id=67" style="font-size: 10px;">текст</a>

Не могу понять почему применяется экранирование

Comment: Предоставьте более полный код, сложно что-то понять

Comment: где экранированный текст?

Comment: В том месте, где должна вывестись ссылка

Comment: Если это в `GridView`, то добавьте атрибут `'format' => 'raw'`

Answer (score 1):

В `GridView`:

```
'value' => function ($model) {
    return Html::a(текст, $model->getUrl(), ['style' => ['font-size' => '10px']]); 
},
'format' => 'raw'
```

Comment: Помогло. Запись "'format' => 'raw'" для того и существует, чтоб деэкранировать?

Comment: @Oughtem нет, параметр `format` указывает в каком формате выводить данные, по умолчанию - `text`. О форматах посмотрите на компонент [`\yii\i18n\Formatter`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter)